# CNTK deactivate gpu locking with python API

Tags: python, cntk

How can I deactivate the GPU locking by `cntk` from the python API (2.0 beta 12.0) such that multiple users may use the same GPU?

If I execute the cntk tutorial 201B from https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Tutorials the training works fine, but all other users / processes get the error message: "Failed to lock GPU 0 for exclusive use" when executing cntk based optimizations.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any libraries you use? Please edit your question. Consider reading [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the device explicitly using GPU id:

```
cntk.device.set_default_device(cntk.device.gpu(0))
```

That way you can run multiple jobs on the same GPU.